# Problems with markers in an AR.js panorama

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, ar.js

I'm building an AR panorama with [AR.js](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js) and would like to have markers floating above landmarks. I tried a [sample provided in AR.js git](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/blob/master/aframe/examples/location-based/always-face-user/) but it’s always the same bug, the marker is not synchronized with the object/landmark when I’m moving the camera, it doesn't stay at the right place. In the beginning, I thought my coordinates were wrong but they are not, I tried both in GPS mode and in simulated/forced location mode (double-checking my location with a handheld Garmin GPS12) for the user location.

Here is a [video of the problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jx3d0iecxh0se4a/video-720p.mp4?dl=0) (we see the marker doesn't stay above the obelisk).

Here is my HTML code, which is pretty close to the sample.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>GeoAR.js demo</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-look-at-component@0.8.0/dist/aframe-look-at-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/3.3.1/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    <a-scene
      vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
      embedded
      arjs="sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;"
    >
      <!-- Obélisque : https://geohack.toolforge.org/geohack.php?language=fr&pagename=Ob%C3%A9lisque%20de%20Louxor&params=48.8655_N_2.3211_E_scale:8000 -->
      <!-- WGS84 48.8655°, 2.3211° -->
      <a-image
        src="location.png"
        look-at="[gps-camera]"
        scale="14 14 14"
        gps-entity-place="latitude: 48.8655; longitude: 2.3211;"
      ></a-image>
      <a-text
        value="Obélisque de Louxor"
        look-at="[gps-camera]"
        scale="14 14 14"
        position="0 40 0"
        align="center"
        gps-entity-place="latitude: 48.8655; longitude: 2.3211;"
      ></a-text>
      <!-- force GPS coordinates -->
      <!-- GPS12: 48.86650 2.32210 80M -->
      <!-- Apple Map: 48.866766 2.322606 -->
      <a-camera gps-camera="simulateLatitude: 48.8665; simulateLongitude: 2.3221; simulateAltitude: 80m;" rotation-reader></a-camera>
      <!-- <a-camera gps-camera rotation-reader></a-camera> -->
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is your video using the simulateLatitude or the gps's one?

Comment: for the accent in obélisque: https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/text.html#non-ascii-characters

Comment: @ElioDiaz Yes, it was using the simulateLatitude... Did you experience such problem?